# Xforwarding doesn't allow for switching users

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, x-windows, x11-forwarding

I'm ssh'd into a remote computer and xforwarding is working fine... but as soon as I "sudo su -" or "sudo su user2" it no longer Xforwards anything giving me the error:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: this is more due to X permissions than X forwarding -- the user you've logged into with SSH has permission to connect to the X display, but when you switch users with 'sudo' the user you're switching to doesn't have those permissions.

Comment: There should be a work around though... I have root access, I should be able to run an X11-forwarded app as a different user.  How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 6):

1. Enable X-11 Forwarding in your client
2. Log in as your normal user
3. `echo $DISPLAY` to get the associated display
4. `xauth list`, find the display number which corresponds with what you found in #3 and copy it
5. Sudo to root `xauth add <paste in what you copied from #4>`
6. Now you can execute commands as root and will be able to se the X11 Forwarding connection

Answer (score 5):

Before you `sudo`, do this:

```
$ xauth extract /tmp/xauthstuff $DISPLAY
```

After you `sudo`, do this:

```
# xauth merge /tmp/xauthstuff
```

Does this work for you?

PS remember to `rm /tmp/xauthstuff` afterwards

Comment: I tried that command and it failed:
 $ xauth extract /tmp/xauthstuff $DISPLAY
 No matches found, authority file "/tmp/xauthstuff" not written
Ideas?

Comment: What does `echo $DISPLAY` produce?

Comment: DISPLAY has the value localhost:10.0

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to root account to do any of the above, so here is a work around that I used.

First, ssh to your account like you normally do and test everything is working.

```
ssh -Y <you>@<your_server>
```

I usually just fire up an XTerm to ensure I have connectivity.  If all good, copy .XAuthority file that is in `<you>` home directory and put it in a public directory.

`cp ~/.Xauthority /tmp/tempXAuth`

Make sure you chmod 777 on that file in the public directory so that the sudo account can use it in the later step.

`chmod 777 /tmp/tempXAuth`

now sudo to the user you need to do work as

`sudo su - <other_user>`

once you are `<other_user>`, back up the existing .Xauthority and then copy the "good" one over.

```
cp ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.bak
cp /tmp/tempXAuth ~/.Xauthority
```

you should be able to run any X programs and have them authenticate with your current XServer session.

Answer (score 2):

Before you `sudo su user2` check the permissions on your $XAUTHORITY:

`echo $XAUTHORITY
 
ls -l $XAUTHORITY`

If after switching user you still reference the same $XAUTHORITY but have lost permissions to the file, then this will break X11 forwarding.
In my case a quick solution was to adjust the file permissions on the $XAUTHORITY file before switching user. 
Keep in mind that if users you don't trust gain access to your $XAUTHORITY file this could be a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the user that you normally log in as type:

```
cd

sudo cp .Xauthority /root/
```

Then you can switch to root using:

```
sudo su
```